# Problema al reproducir sonido en una img

Tags: javascript, html

Saludos, quiero cambiar el src de una etiqueta para poder reproducir un sonido en función de la imagen pulsada.

El código original es :

```
<head>
    <script>
        function EvalSound(soundobj) {
            var thissound= eval("document." soundobj);
            thissound.Play();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <embed src="animales/perro.mp3" autostart=false width=0 height=0 name="sound1" enablejavascript="true">
    <img src="play.gif" onClick="EvalSound('sound1')">
</body>
```

Funciona pero siempre reproduce al perro.

Le he modificado :

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function EvalSound(soundobj) {
            document.getElementById("reproductor").src = soundobj;
            var thissound= eval("document." soundobj);
            thissound.Play();
        }
    </script>
</head> 
<body> 
    <embed src="" autostart=false id="reproductor" width=0 height=0 name="sound1" enablejavascript="true">
    <main>
        <div class="" id="midiv"> 
            <img id="leon" src="animales/leon.jpg" onClick="EvalSound('animales/leon.mp3')" alt="León" />
            <img id="Halcon" src="animales/halcon.jpg" onClick="EvalSound('animales/halcon.mp3')" alt="Halcón" />
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
```

La lógica es sencilla : Recojo la ruta del sonido cuando llamo a la función y luego cambio el src del embebe pero no funciona....

Solución::

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            var audio = new Audio();;

            function EvalSound(soundobj) { 
                if(audio.play()){
                 audio.pause();
                 audio = null;
                 audio = new Audio(soundobj);
                 audio.play(); 
                }                
            }
</script>

    <div class="" id="midiv"> 
        <img id="leon" src="animales/leon.jpg"       onClick="EvalSound('animales/leon.mp3')" alt="León"  />
        <img id="Halcon" src="animales/halcon.jpg"   onClick="EvalSound('animales/halcon.mp3')"  alt="Halcón"  />
    </div>
```

Comment: a esta línea: `eval("document." soundobj)` no le faltará un + para concatenar los strings? soy más de jQuery, pero es una duda que me ha entrado ahora al ver esa línea. no te da ningún error la consola?

Comment: venía en el código original de la pág y funciona así, el problema es cuando quiero q sea según yo pulso una img u otra.

Comment: Cuando le doy no funciona, no se reproduce, pero si voy al apartado consola, empieza a sonar el audio...

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: animales is not defined
    at eval (eval at EvalSound (index.html:4), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at EvalSound (index.html:45)
    at HTMLImageElement.onclick (index.html:66)
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type audio/mp3: "file:///G:/unidad%206/Propuesta4/animales/leon.mp3".

Comment: Haz probado con algo como `var audio = new Audio('audio.mp3');` y le pasas la ruta como parámetro?

Comment: No sería mejor, en una variable, incluir el elemento, hacer un Stop(); y entonces ahí cambias el src y le vuelves a dar el play? total, si vas a cambiar de sonido, el anterior se va a quitar, si le haces un Stop() puedes ahorrarte ese eval() que a mi no me cuadra, ya que casi nunca lo he usado

Comment: Gracias Federico, lo usé como solución.

Answer (score 1):

Basándome en [esto](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_audio_play), he hecho un ejemplo similar a lo que tenías utilizando la etiqueta `<audio>`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function EvalSound(src) {
      document.getElementById("sonido").src = src;
      var audio = document.getElementById("reproductor");
      audio.load();
      audio.play();
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <audio id="reproductor">
    <source id="sonido" src="" type="audio/mpeg">.
  </audio>
  <div class="" id="midiv">
    <img id="leon" src="animales/leon.jpg" onClick="EvalSound('animales/leon.mp3')" alt="León" />
    <img id="Halcon" src="animales/halcon.jpg" onClick="EvalSound('animales/halcon.mp3')" alt="Halcón" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Justamente ahora he encontrado una solución, gracias por tu tiempo amigo =).